# Java: Adding Elements to Vector From Hashmap Multiple Times

Tags: java, vector, hashmap

I'm trying to go over a hashmap of rooms in a maze and add ones that are outer rooms to a Vector. Rooms keep getting added multiple times, can anyone help me figure out why?

```
public void fillOuterRoomVector()
{
    //initialize the vector
    outerRooms = new Vector<Room>();

    //for each one
    for(Entry<String, Room> e : mazeRooms.entrySet()) 
    {
        //if it is outer
        if (e.getValue().isThisAnOuterRoom()==true)
        {
            //add it
            outerRooms.add(e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I checked in the Variables view in Eclipse while I debugged, the rooms really appear only once in mazeRooms and more than once in outerRooms

EDIT: [image: Screenshot from debug screen]

Comment: How is `mazeRooms` populated?  Can it contain duplicate `Room`'s with different keys?

Comment: might be that an Instace of Room resides multiple times in the Map? that can explains it. You do not check of uniqness of the Room instance.

Comment: it's a hashmap of Rooms with String keys, and each room appears in it exactly once

Comment: Not true if you are seeing the same room added to `outerRooms` multiple times.  Your logic wouldn't allow duplicates unless there are duplicates in the `mazeRooms.values()`.

Comment: Because the map contains multiple references to the same room. Side notes: Vector shouldn't be used anymore. Use ArrayList instead. And `if (e.getValue().isThisAnOuterRoom())` is sufficient. No need for `== true`. A boolean expression evaluates to a boolean.

Comment: I checked in the Variables view in Eclipse while I debugged, the rooms appear only once in mazeRooms and more than once in outerRooms

Comment: Then it means that the vector is not a local variable as shown in your snippet, but is a field or a parameter that is filled several times. It wouldn't be surprising since, as it is, the method doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: @JB it does in the rest of the program.  In terms of the boolean, I just like writing it like that, it's easier to look at.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that there is no duplicate entry object (which is expected). That doesn't mean that two entries don't contain the same room. And map entries are chained, so your screenshot doesn't show all the rooms. Call toString() on the map, and check that rooms are duplicated. And sorry, I misread the code and thought the vector was a local variable, which it is not.

Comment: You can verify that there are no duplicate values using this expression: `assert mazeRooms.size() == (new HashSet(mazeRooms.values())).size()`. You can add this temporarily just for debugging purposes

Comment: @JB tried the toString() you suggested, still didn't see any duplicates...thanks for trying to help though :)

Comment: You can also just add a System.out.println( e.getValue().toString() ); before your if statement and check to see if you have a duplicate there.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the data, my guess would be that mazeRooms has the same value with multiple keys.  If your need is to have a Collection of non-duplicated data, I would recommend using a `Set` instead of a `Vector`.

Answer (score 0):

If the same room gets added to `outerRooms()` more than once, this means that it was present in `mazeRooms` more than once (with different keys).

Comment: I checked in the Variables view in Eclipse while I debugged, the rooms appear only once in mazeRooms and more than once in outerRooms

Comment: @BIU: With respect, that doesn't seem likely. Things are sometimes not what they look like. Could you produce a complete example that we could run and that demonstrate this behaviour?

Comment: thanks...the program uses a lot of different files though so I don't know how I could do that.  can I send a screenshot of the debug screen to show you what I mean?

Comment: @BIU: Sure, feel free to attach the screenshot to your question.

Comment: that's what I'm seeing (image added)

Comment: @BIU: Unfortunately, that screenshot is showing us the *entries* of `mazeRooms` rather than the *values*. There could still be multiple entries with different keys and pointing to the same value (e.g. `Room (id=49)`). We can't tell from the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashSet instead of a Vector to ensure that each Room is recorded only once.